# How should I react if my supervisor for my master thesis gives me low quality supporting information?

Tags: thesis, masters, advisor

Currently, I am writing my master thesis at a German university. My work has a lot of to do with programming. However, there are some parts I need, but it is not part of my work. For this case, my supervisor told me if I need anything I can ask him and he will do this for me (as long as it is not part of my topic).

Unfortunately, the quality of work my supervisor delivers me is very bad. Basically, I would do it by myself, however the time scheduling is quite tight, which is why I am quite thankful that he tries to support me.

How can I handle this without making him angry or upset. I am quite thankful that he "helps" me, but when I look at the quality, I am thinking that I could have just done the work myself.

I still have to work with my adviser for about half a year more.

Comment: You'll need to be more clear about when you mean by 'quality'. Is it code you just don't like the look of (don't like the style, hard for you to understand, slow), or materials that are blatantly wrong and ultimately unusable and are a waste of everyone's time?

Comment: What is the predicament here? I don't see a situation to be solved. The question does not specify i) if he expects to see his work appear in yours, ii) if he asked for your feedback about his work, iii) why do you have to let him know your thought about the quality of his work, and iv) whether you are going to do the work yourself (the question just says "I could have.")

Comment: The best would be to clarify only what you can not do/learn by yourself in the meetings with the supervisor, and establish more often meetings with him(perhaps 2-3 per week).

Answer (score 1):

Working with a supervisor is like working with a manager.

In both cases, they can only help you as well as you empower them to help you.

Ask yourself about previous 'help' moments you required from your supervisor:
what went well and not so well about it?
why was it not as helpful as you wished it would be?
how can you help your supervisor be more efficient and effective at helping you?

More often than not, things boil down to communication issues.

You need to provide all the information that you have and that your supervisor may need to help you. You also need to be able to convey to your supervisor what you expect from what they will help you with.